# Consider the subset $B=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1\}\ \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $\vert B \vert = \vert \mathbb{R}^2 \vert$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Consider the subset $B=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1\}\ \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $\vert B \vert = \vert \mathbb{R}^2 \vert$.

It is easy to see tht $f:B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $f(x,y)=(x,y)$ is injective.

However, in the book I'm working out of (Book of Proof by Richard Hammack), the other injection noted is

$g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow B$ defined as

$$g(x,y)=\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2+1}x,\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2+1}y\right).$$

In the book I'm asked to verify this is indeed an injective function.

My approach was to assume $g(x,y)=g(m,n)$ and through basic algebra I was able to deduce

$x(m^2+n^2+1)(x^2+y^2)=m(x^2+y^2+1)(m^2+n^2)$

and

$y(m^2+n^2+1)(x^2+y^2)=n(x^2+y^2+1)(m^2+n^2)$

but how does this show $(x,y)=(m,n)$? Or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: I may not understand what you are actually asking for but it is obvious that $x^2+y^2\leq y$.

Comment: @tatan I'm trying to understand how to show $g$ is injective. My approach was to show $g(x,y)=g(m,n)\Rightarrow (x,y)=(m,n)$. But I can't see how to prove this conditional statement true.

Comment: @ClownInMoon Ok. But as for the question in the title, it's quite obvious

Answer (score 1):

In the original $f(\mathbf{u})=f(\mathbf{v})$ where $\mathbf{u}=(x,y)$ and $\mathbf{v}=(m,n)$ and $||\cdot||$ is the Euclidean norm:

$\frac{||\mathbf{u}||^2}{||\mathbf{u}||^2+1}\mathbf{\mathbf{u}}=\frac{||\mathbf{v}||^2}{||\mathbf{v}||^2+1}\mathbf{v}$

Take norm both sides:

$\frac{||\mathbf{u}||^3}{||\mathbf{u}||^2+1}=\frac{||\mathbf{v}||^3}{||\mathbf{v}||^2+1}$

Use injectivity of $f(t)=\frac{t^3}{t^2+1}$ to get $||\mathbf{u}||=||\mathbf{v}||$

Then simplify the initial equation to get $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{v}$

Comment: .. and what is nice is that it works for the n-dimensional case...